# How to resolve "javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package a.b.c"?

Tags: java, maven, warnings, package, javadoc

I am very much outdated, but I have just upgraded my project to use JDK 1.5 from JDK 1.4, and now when running `mvn javadoc:javadoc`, I encounter the following javadoc warnings:

```
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package "com.a"
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package "com.b"
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package "com.c"
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package "com.a"
```

What do I need to do to fix them?  Has anything changed from JDK 1.4 to 1.5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Updated 10 years after the original answer.)*

An old [thread in the Oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1521129&tstart=60) discussed this. *(Unfortunately the link is broken now, and I can't find the same thread in the new Oracle Developer community, nor [in the Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1521129))*.

As far as I recall (and could gather from a bit of google-ing), the behavior of javadoc changed between JDK 1.4 and 1.5 so that a package documentation encountered multiple times creates this warning.
This seems to have happened specifically with older versions of Maven – updating to a newer version of Maven (or the maven-javadoc-plugin) seems to have helped.

(Of course, that meant a Maven version which was current in 2011, so any version you might have nowadays should be fine.)

Comment: Unfortunately the link is not valid anymore. It would be helpful if you could update the answer.

Comment: @Janothan I couldn't find a newer link for the same content (this was 10 years ago), but I've added a bit of details I've found.