# javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package "org.osgi.framework"

Tags: java, maven, osgi, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm working on eclipse RCP project where maven and osgi are used.

When i run `mvn javadoc:javadoc`, I'm getting `Multiple sources of package comments found for package "org.osgi.framework"` warning.

What could be the reason for this warning?

Comment: Which version of maven are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package a.b.c"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788637/how-to-resolve-javadoc-warning-multiple-sources-of-package-comments-found-fo)

Comment: @andreas I'm using maven 2.5

Comment: Please try a current maven 3 version

Comment: tried maven version 3.3.9, still no luck

Comment: I get this same issue on Gradle. Did you ever figure out why it's happening?